# Files are not received when sending form data to the server

Tags: asp.net, aurelia

I am trying to send form data to my server (Asp.net server), but when debugging the server only the typed information is received, but the files are not there.

This is my html page: (http://pastebin.com/KZERsepn)

```
<template>
<ai-dialog>
    <ai-dialog-body>
        <div>
            <span>character name</span>
            <input type="text" value.bind="user.name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Youtube url:</span>
            <input type="text" value.bind="user.YoutubeUrl" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>ProfileImage:</span>
            <input type="file" file.bind="user.ProfileImage" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>CoverImage:</span>
            <input type="file" file.bind="user.CoverImage" />
        </div>
    </ai-dialog-body>

    <ai-dialog-footer>
        <button click.trigger="controller.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button click.trigger="controller.ok(user)">Ok</button>
    </ai-dialog-footer>
</ai-dialog>
```

and this is how i am posting the data:(http://pastebin.com/7bVHZthE)

```
createUser(user) {
    let model = new FormData();
    model.append('Name', user.Name);
    model.append('YoutubeUrl', user.YoutubeUrl);
    model.append('ProfileImage', user.ProfileImage);
    model.append('CoverImage', user.CoverImage);

    return this.client.fetch('/api/createUser', {
        method: "post",
        body: model,
        headers: {
            'Access-Controll-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    });
}
```

But only the user.name and user.youtubeurl properties are sent to the server.

Comment: Please include your relevant code here.

Answer (score 2):

### To post files, you must use a multipart/form-data

The trick to posting a `multipart/form-data` is (rather unintuitively) to force the content-type header to `false`. So try this:

```
return this.client.fetch('/api/createUser', {
    method: "post",
    body: model,
    headers: {
        'Content-type': '', // this is where the magic happens
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

Comment: if this answer is good, please upvote. if it answered your question, please accept it. <3

Comment: Hey there, adding this line cause my web server to throw this error : "Incorrect Content-Type:"

Comment: your server? that's tricky. try using `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'`, or google further on how to use this particular content type with your particular server